# unable to delete the dns record in gcp using python client

Tags: python-2.7, google-cloud-dns

I need to delete a dns record in gcp. I got the dns record to delete from changes().list() method. As per the document I have appended the record I want to delete to the changes().deletions and called changes().create() method. But I am getting error **Precondition not met for 'entity.change.deletions[0]'**

```
mzone = client.managedZones().get(project=project_id,managedZone='abc-pods').execute()
        changes = client.changes().list(project=project_id,managedZone='abc-pods').execute()
        records_to_delete = []
        for change in changes['changes']:
            for record in change['additions']:
                if dnsname in record['name']:
                    records_to_delete.append(change)
        for record in records_to_delete:
            record['deletions'].append(record['additions'][1])
            record['additions'].remove(record['additions'][1])
        for record in records_to_delete:
            r = client.changes().create(project=project_id, managedZone='abd-pods', body=record).execute()
            pprint.pprint(r)
```

Json I got from changes().list:

```
    {u'additions': [{u'kind': u'dns#resourceRecordSet',
                  u'name': u'abc.com.',
                  u'rrdatas': [u'ns-cloud-c1.googledomains.com. cloud-dns-hostmaster.google.com. 2118 21600 3600 259200 300'],
                  u'signatureRrdatas': [],
                  u'ttl': 21600,
                  u'type': u'SOA'},
                 {u'kind': u'dns#resourceRecordSet',
                  u'name': u'xxx.abc.com.',
                  u'rrdatas': [u'34.76.78.35'],
                  u'signatureRrdatas': [],
                  u'ttl': 30,
                  u'type': u'A'}],
  u'deletions': [{u'kind': u'dns#resourceRecordSet',
                  u'name': u'abc.com.',
                  u'rrdatas': [u'ns-cloud-c1.googledomains.com. cloud-dns-hostmaster.google.com. 2117 21600 3600 259200 300'],
                  u'signatureRrdatas': [],
                  u'ttl': 21600,
                  u'type': u'SOA'}],
  u'id': u'2184',
  u'kind': u'dns#change',
  u'startTime': u'2020-07-13T18:04:34.896Z',
  u'status': u'done'}
```

Modified Json given to changes().create() method:

```
{u'additions': [{u'kind': u'dns#resourceRecordSet',
                  u'name': u'abc.com.',
                  u'rrdatas': [u'ns-cloud-c1.googledomains.com. cloud-dns-hostmaster.google.com. 2118 21600 3600 259200 300'],
                  u'signatureRrdatas': [],
                  u'ttl': 21600,
                  u'type': u'SOA'}],
  u'deletions': [{u'kind': u'dns#resourceRecordSet',
                  u'name': u'abc.com.',
                  u'rrdatas': [u'ns-cloud-c1.googledomains.com. cloud-dns-hostmaster.google.com. 2117 21600 3600 259200 300'],
                  u'signatureRrdatas': [],
                  u'ttl': 21600,
                  u'type': u'SOA'},
                 {u'kind': u'dns#resourceRecordSet',
                  u'name': u'xxx.abc.com.',
                  u'rrdatas': [u'34.76.78.35'],
                  u'signatureRrdatas': [],
                  u'ttl': 30,
                  u'type': u'A'}],
  u'id': u'2184',
  u'kind': u'dns#change',
  u'startTime': u'2020-07-13T18:04:34.896Z',
  u'status': u'done'}
```

As per the document, the body for create() method is same as the response from list() method. But still, I am not able to delete a record. Any idea what am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Try to review the following articles that I found which could be matching a similar issue:

- [GitHub-Precondition not met #6036](https://github.com/certbot/certbot/issues/6036)
- [GitHub-GCP error 412](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/external-dns/issues/467)

2. Make sure the account used by the python code has the right permissions
3. Review the Cloud DNS articles and make sure you're following the exact syntax:

- [ManagedZones-delete](https://cloud.google.com/dns/docs/reference/v1/managedZones/delete)